# MVC5 Razor Value cannot be null or empty. Parameter name: name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

> Source error: Line 22:         @Html.TextBoxFor(model =>
>   model.DailyCurrencyRates___BuyingCurrency, new { @id = "test", @class
>   = "form-control" })

I am stuck on this issue for days and cannot get round this error. I simply want to render a partial view with the items for parent class. below is my code: Please ask for more info if needed.

Controller

```
public ActionResult AddRecord(int index)
{
  return PartialView("_AddItem", new ForexItem { Index = index});
}
```

Parent View

```
@foreach (ForexItem item in Model.ForexItems)
{
    Html.RenderPartial("_AddItem", item);
}
```

Partial View

```
@model F.Models.Entities.ForexItem

@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DailyCurrencyRates___BuyingCurrency, new { @id = "test", @class = "form-control" })
```

Model

```
public partial class ForexItem
 {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        [StringLength(1000)]
        [Display(Name = "Buying")]
        public string DailyCurrencyRates___BuyingCurrency { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public int Index { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: can you share full error, as I don't see any issue in the code.

Comment: @AnupamSingh full error line22: Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Value cannot be null or empty. Parameter name: name  ArgumentException: Value cannot be null or empty.
Parameter name: name]
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.InputHelper(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, InputType inputType, ModelMetadata metadata, String name, Object value, Boolean useViewData, Boolean isChecked, Boolean setId, Boolean isExplicitValue, String format, IDictionary`2 htmlAttributes) +1081
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.TextBoxFor(HtmlHelper`1 htmlHelper, Expression`1 expression, String format,

Comment: try to put a breakpoint on line : Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DailyCurrencyRates___BuyingCurrency, new { id = "test", class = "form-control" })
and see what is null.

Comment: putting a breakpoint is no help; all model props are initialized. It seems that in parent view inside the for loop i have tried using Html.partial and Html.Render Action but still same error

Comment: the way you are using Html.RenderPartial is correct

Comment: I am puzzled as I have used the same pattern in other projects but cannot get past this error.

Comment: Does `@Html.TextBox("DailyCurrencyRates___BuyingCurrency")` work?

Comment: This seems to be a pretty obvious mistake.  Your controller method is returning a `ForexItem`.  You haven't given us the `@model` used in the view, but based on your view code the model should have a  `ForexItems` property which `ForexItem` in your controller method either doesn't have or isn't setting.

Answer (score 4):

I obtained that same vague, obscure error when I increased the number of underscores in a model property name from 1 to 2.  Note that the error did not occur for the LabelFor Helper directly before the TextBoxFor helper, but just in the TextBoxFor helper, same as you got.  (I notice your property name ("DailyCurrencyRates___BuyingCurrency") has 3 underscores.)  It then went away when I removed the extra underscore from the property name.  It was as though with the extra underscore, Razor could not find the property name, so it just searched for (generic) "name" instead, which it also could not find.

Comment: OMG, thank you for posting this...same thing - issue with double underscores in the field name (carry over from a SalesForce naming model).  Changing the models used by the views to have a single underscore fixed the issue.

Comment: Note, this happened after upgrading the MVC libraries (NuGet packages) from v3.2.3 targeting .NET 4.5.2 to v3.2.6 targeting .NET 4.6.2

<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.2.6" targetFramework="net462" />

Also, Microsoft.Net.Compilers went from v3.1.1 to v3.2.0

Comment: FWIW, the MS code uses ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText() to evaluate the name param, and in that method it explicitly returns string.Empty if it encounters a double underscore in the member property name, which leads to the OP's error.

Answer (score 1):

It may be a typo, but it seems to me that you should change `Model.ForexItems` to `Model.ForexItem` - no s. Based on your submitted code.
… or maybe just use `Model` since you already put ForexItem in as that?

**Parent View**

```
@foreach (ForexItem item in Model)
{
    Html.RenderPartial("_AddItem", item);
}
```